# How to configure in memory persistence?

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

I have placed `application.conf` file in `test/resources` directory.

It contains:

```
akka.persistence {
  journal.plugin = "inmemory-journal"
  snapshot-store.plugin = "inmemory-snapshot-store"
}
```

But whenever I run tests I get error:

> requirement failed: 'reference.conf' is missing persistence plugin config path: 'inmemory-journal'

What should I add to configuration?

Comment: Did you add the dependency to your build.sbt?

Comment: @BennieKrijger Yep, that was my mistake =) I added it to wrong project. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

For the journal:

```
akka.persistence.journal.plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.inmem"
```

There is no in memory snapshot store.

Comment: Ok, but how could I found out this string `akka.persistence.journal.inmem` ?

Comment: So I see this is the package in `akka-persistence_2.11-2.4.20.jar`. But what is the purpose of [akka-peristence-inmemory](https://github.com/dnvriend/akka-persistence-inmemory) lib?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix this issue by adding the below property
akka.persistence.internal-stash-overflow-strategy="akka.persistence.ThrowExceptionConfigurator"